# How to get word timestamp given an audio and its transcript?

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition

Hi I am working on timestamp generation for my transcript. I have already had the transcript.

I am wondering if there is more accurate way to get timestamp besides algorithms like Montreal-forced-alignment. They have some accuracy issue to me.

Comment: aeneas ........